# Как задать координаты кластера в Yandex maps?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

С помощью ROM реализую серверную кластеризацию данных. Собрал точки в кластер. Не понятно, как задать координаты кластера.

```
var zoom = req.query.z;
var requestBbox = req.query.bbox;
var arrayBbox = requestBbox.split(',');
var bbox = [];
var filteredFeatures = [];
var sortedFeatures;
var clusteredFeatures = [];
var clusterPresets = ["islands#yellowClusterIcons"];
var clusterCount;
var tempFeatures = [];
if (zoom < 12) {
    clusterCount = 100;
} else {
    if (zoom >= 12 && zoom < 16) {
        clusterCount = 50;
    } else { clusterCount = 20 };
};
for (var i = 0; i < arrayBbox.length; i++) {
    bbox[i] = parseFloat(arrayBbox[i])
};
for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
    if (features[i].geometry.coordinates[0] >= bbox[0] &&
        features[i].geometry.coordinates[0] <= bbox[2] &&
        features[i].geometry.coordinates[1] >= bbox[1] &&
        features[i].geometry.coordinates[1] <= bbox[3]
    ) {
        filteredFeatures.push(features[i])
    };
};
if (filteredFeatures.length >= clusterCount) {
    //принял за центр координаты средней точки массива объектов
    var pointIndex = Math.round(filteredFeatures.length / 2);
    var clusterCoords = filteredFeatures[pointIndex].geometry.coordinates;
    clusteredFeatures.push({
        type: 'Cluster',
        id: clusterId,
        geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: clusterCoords
        },
        features: filteredFeatures,
        bbox: [
            [bbox[0], bbox[1]],
            [bbox[2], bbox[3]]
        ],
        number: filteredFeatures.length,
        properties: {
            "iconContent": filteredFeatures.length
        },
        options: {
            'preset': clusterPresets,//[clusterId % clusterPresets.length],
            'clusterDisableClickZoom': true,
            'clusterBalloonContentLayout': "cluster#balloonAccordion"
        }
    });
    clusterId++;
}
else {
    filteredFeatures.length;
    for (i = 0; i < filteredFeatures.length; i++) {
        clusteredFeatures.push(filteredFeatures[i])
    };
}
```

Какой алгоритм центровки кластера относительно кластеризуемых точек?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ROM'у все равно какие координаты вы задаете кластеру. Самый простой вариант - поставить кластер в точку со арифметически средним значением lat и long.

Comment: Может сработать. Спасибо!